# How to solve $\int \frac{dx}{x+x^2}$ without using partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, integration

I can easily rewrite it as $\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1}$, but is it possible to solve this without partial fractions?

Comment: I have another solution, you can differentiate $$x \mapsto \ln\left(x\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+x^2\right)$$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I just fixed it

Comment: Substitute $y=1/x$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  It is in fact true that $\frac 1{x+x^2)} = \frac 1x - \frac 1{x+1}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle y=1+\frac{1}{x}$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{x+x^2}&=-\int\frac{\frac{-1}{x^2}dx}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\\
&=-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)+C
\end{align*}